# How to authentication React Front End with back-end Node.js Express-Sessions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm moving away from using firestore auth to understand how to make my own authentication system.

My goal:

1. Create a react web app that lets user sign up and sign in .
2. Authenticated users can operate on restAPI, which is NodeJS hooked up to Postgres.

I've watched a lot of tutorials. Most of them talk about express-sessions as as solution. However, when i tried it - these session cookie are only provided when my browser is on the express uri.

The issue is...
On the front-end, when I send CRUD operation via fetch to my express api, my react-app do not get that cookie.

is what I'm doing the conventional way to handle authentication with backend server? How can i fix this?

EXPRESS:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const db = require("./db");
var session = require("express-session");
var pgSession = require("connect-pg-simple")(session);

const app = express(); //create an instance;
// :id url param.
app.use(
    session({
      store: new pgSession({ pool: db.pool }),
      secret: "secret",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { maxAge: 303 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, //30days
    })
  );

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-Access-Token,XKey,Authorization"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post("/addUser", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const results = await db.query(
      "INSERT INTO USERS (email, password) values ($1, $2) returning *",
      [req.body.email, req.body.password]
    );
    console.log(results);
    req.session.isAuth = true;
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        user: results.rows,
      },
    });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

ReactJS

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:3006/addUser", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setAuthenticated(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <router path="/" exact>
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
              <label>email</label>
              <input
                name="email"
                type="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <label>password</label>
              <input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
            </form>
          </div>
          {authenticated ? <Redirect to="/auth" /> : null}
        </router>
        <Route path="/auth" exact>
          Authenticated
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

in React - after submitting the form, cookies didnt show up in the devtools.

Comment: Could you please share your server code and API URL example?

Comment: yes, ive updated it. please take a look. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In Server

- Please enable cors(install cors library).

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}))
```

- Add session configuration.

```
app.use(
  session({
    key: 'sid',
    secret: Secret_String,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      sameSite: 'none',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      maxAge: 1000000000, // ten seconds, for testing
    },
    store: store, // postgres session store
  }),
);
```

2. In Client,
   You have to use `withcredentials` option when calling API.

- Chrome disabled set-cookie for different origin from 85.0 version. So, the set-cookie wont be work. You have to disable secure option in chrome.
  Please go to chrome://flags -> Cookies without SameSite must be secure -> disabled

3. In your code

```
fetch("http://localhost:3006/addUser", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
})
```

Comment: is the headers provided manually for CORS not enough ?

Comment: You can check set-cookie option in browser devtools -> network

Comment: It is important to disable the secure option in chrome settings.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. I will most likely have to read up CORS. also i have never had a problem fetching without 'withcrediential' esp getting data from previous public api's i.e. jsonplaceholder. so im not sure what it is.  if u could answer, in this setup is it safe for me to deploy for production , or is more of a patch work for local development? and what is the standard way. thank you so much.

Comment: with sameSite: 'none', and chrome flags off. To me it feels like my entire approach is unsafe from the beginning to allow it work practically in the real world.

Comment: Chrome browser disabled Set-Cookie script from 85.0 for secuity.